# Sprite not disappearing

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit, physics, skspritenode

Here is my code. I am trying to create a space shooter game and when the alien hits the bottom of the screen, I want the player to disappear. I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with this code.

```
 func gameOver() {
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    borderBody.categoryBitMask = borderCategory


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        }else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & alienCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & borderCategory) != 0 {
            player.removeFromParent()
        }
```

Comment: There is little information from your code.  Nobody even knows how a node called player is created.

Comment: Is your `didBegin` method really inside your `gameOver` method?

Comment: El tomato, I created my player by doing:  player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shuttle")
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 100 , y: -300)
        player.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(player)

Comment: rmaddy, im pretty sure my didBegin method is inside my gameOver method...

Comment: That is wrong then,  didbegin needs to be in your class that has the physics delegate. If it is in your gameover, it will never be called.

Comment: this worked thank you! :)